# How to controll Mysql query execution time?

Tags: mysql, time

I have several EVENTS executing every two seconds, I would like to kill those which are 
running longer than 1 second.

Are there way to control query execution time on MySQL 5.5?

cheers Arman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command to see running processes in MySQL.

Here's a link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-processlist.html.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me an idea to make a new EVENT with process list filter.